# Android. AlertDialog. Как изменить цвет фона у кнопок?

Tags: java, android, android-style, android-dialog, android-button

Как изменить цвет кнопок в АлертДиалоге?

[image: На данный момент диалог выглядит вот так]

В разметке диалога задаю

```
android:background="@color/background_window"
```

все, кроме кнопок подсвечивается серым цветом

пробую вот так:

```
dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MyApplication.getAppContext(), R.color.background_window));
```

приложение падает при открытии диалога

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение выше перекрашивает только бакграунд у кнопок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По сути ответ на вопрос был закоментирован в ответе выше

Перед открытием диалога вставил строчку:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.background_window);
```

и все заработало:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Странно, что строка в разметке не устанавливает бэкграунд для панели кнопок

Answer (score 1):

На en-SO [пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35333129/3212712), что можно повесить слушатель показа диалога и уже в нём менять фон кнопкам, т.к. в этот момент диалог уже создан.

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(context1);
    adb.setTitle(context1.getString(R.string.app_name))
    .setMessage(message)
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
});
AlertDialog dialog = adb.create();

// Make some UI changes for AlertDialog
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {

        // Add or create your own background drawable for AlertDialog window
        //Window view = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getWindow();
        //view.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);

        // Customize POSITIVE, NEGATIVE and NEUTRAL buttons.
        Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positiveButton.setTextColor(context1.getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
        positiveButton.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        positiveButton.invalidate();

        Button negativeButton = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        negativeButton.setTextColor(context1.getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
        negativeButton.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        negativeButton.invalidate();

        Button neutralButton = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
        neutralButton.setTextColor(context1.getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
        neutralButton.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        neutralButton.invalidate();
    }
});
```