# Как изменить background у ImageView в пользовательском AlertDialog по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: java, android, xml

Как изменить background у ImageView в пользовательском AlertDialog по нажатию кнопки?Кнопка не принадлежит AlertDialog и нажимается до создания AlertDialog

```
final ImageButton ImageButtonPlanet_1;
    ImageButtonPlanet_1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonPlanet_1);
    ImageButtonPlanet_1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    alert.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onShow(final DialogInterface alert) {

                            imageViewNamePlanets.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.planet_name1);

                        }
                    });

                    alert.show();

                    break;

    04-09 16:12:33.489 16679-16679/samsung.ru.spacex E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
04-09 16:12:33.489 16679-16679/samsung.ru.spacex D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-09 16:12:33.489 16679-16679/samsung.ru.spacex W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418a0c08)
04-09 16:12:33.489 16679-16679/samsung.ru.spacex E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: samsung.ru.spacex, PID: 16679
                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                       at samsung.ru.spacex.MainPlanets$2$1.onShow(MainPlanets.java:66)
                                                                       at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMessage(Dialog.java:1261)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5598)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Можно конкретнее, в чём проблема? Почему не использовать .setBackgroundResource(int resId)?

Comment: @DenisPerfomer, я пробовал сделать так, как на скринах, но приложение крашалось.

Comment: У вас что-то null. Что именно - неизвестно т.к. вы выложили лог не до конца и не сказали на какой именно строчке падает. Также имена переменных надо писать с маленькой буквы и не использовать там нижних подчёркиванием. В данный момент ваша проблема плохо сформулирована и помочь вам крайне сложно.

Comment: Это весь лог ошибки. Выпадает из-за строчки  imageViewNamePlanets.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.planet_name1);

Comment: Знчит эта ваша переменная null. Проверьте место где вы её инициализируете, может вы не тот ID используете.

Comment: проверил, все верно,. но все-равно ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите ответы [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509304/17609) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510960/17609).

Идея такова - вешаете слушатель на событие показа диалога и в нём вы можете получить доступ к разметке диалога.

Comment: Я сделал таким способом, но все-равно ошибка. Вот тут скрин моего кода https://postimg.org/image/upu9iu4cn/

Comment: @En1q0d, не надо ссылок на скриншоты. Добавляйте код текстом  в вопрос.

Comment: public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        alert.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onShow(final DialogInterface alert) {

                                imageViewNamePlanets.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.planet_name1);

                            }
                        });

               alert.show();

                       break;

Comment: @En1q0d, в комментрии тоже код не надо писать - дополните свой вопрос через его редактирование.

Comment: @En1q0d, и расскажите что за ошибка, на какой строке и приложите вывод ошибки в логах.

Comment: Добавил код и ошибку в логах

Comment: Это весь лог ошибки. Выпадает из-за строчки imageViewNamePlanets.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.planet_name1);